# How to solve boolean logic equation with prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic, expression

For example, if I have an expression "C = A and B", I want to create some kind of predicate like

```
solv(A, B, C) := C is A, B.
```

to call it like

```
solv(A, true, true).
```

so that Prolog will say "B is true". Please help.

Answer (score -1):

it looks like

```
and(A, B, R) :- A = true, B = true, R = true.
or(A, B, R) :- (A = true ; B = true), R = true.
solve(A, B, C, Result) :- or(A, B, R1), and(R1, C, Result).
```

Comment: Are you looking for predicates that return 'true' or 'false' atoms as explicit results? Or do you want predicates that succeed or fail depending upon the truth value of the expression being tested? Your example is a mixture. They will return 'true' in `R` and succeed if the expression is true, but they will fail and not instantiate `R` if false.

Comment: In addition to @mbratch's remark (+1), your `and/3` would be identically stated `and(true, true, true).`, and your `or/3` would be identically stated `or(true, _, true). or(_, true, true).`. That you went for a much more verbose/indirect formulation for no apparent gain also has me raising the proverbial eyebrow.